# How to get images from slides in ppt file in iPhone or iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, file, powerpoint

I have a ppt file stored in iPad. I want to display that ppt as a slide show. So i will need to convert it to images for best look and feel. How to do it?

I think its basically related to identifying the slides and then storing them as images.

Comment: Hey Aditya .. I am doing the same thing . webView is okay but we cannot do horizontal scrolling there right? did you find anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use QuickLook framework for generating previews for documents, that can be handled by system (like iWorks or MS Office). See more information about this at http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/QuickLook/Reference/QuickLookFrameworkReference_iPhoneOS/_index.html

Comment: Hi! Actually this framework allows you to preview the whole document. If I do remember correctly, it will preview ppt with vertical scrolling. However, I think, you can experiment with rendering this preview in memory and slicing and outputting it in your own way. A brief tutorial about using QuickLook framework can be found here: http://iphonedevelopertips.com/data-file-management/preview-documents-with-qlpreviewcontroller.html or http://robsprogramknowledge.blogspot.com/2011/02/quick-look-for-ios_21.html